# lua script непонятный код

Tags: lua

что-то плохо гуглится. код имеет вид

```
if ['\108\101\110']() == 0 then return end
```

и так всё в этих кодах, думал может это ASCII но нет.

Comment: Над этим скриптом поработал какой-то обфускатор (obfuscator).

Answer (score 3):

Это десятичные ASCII коды. `'\108\101\110' == 'len' == 0x6C 0x65 0x6E`

Похоже на такой хитрый вызов функции `len()`.

Comment: я тоже думал что ASCII, но там есть \166 \254 и прочие, которые соответствуют всяким иероглифам

Comment: @ke1evra Почему вы тогда не покажите тот кусок скрипта и не спрашиваете про него в вопросе? Этот ответ абсолютно верен и на 100% правильно объясняет кусок кода, приведенного в вопросе.